Compiling MPSolve
MPSolve is a popular library for numerically solving polynomial equations. I would like to compile it on my Ubuntu WSL2 distribution. I have downloaded the latest release 3.2.1, and attempted to compile it by following the instructions on the MPSolve website:
tar xvf mpsolve-x.y.z.tar.gz
cd mpsolve-x.y.z
./configure 
make 

However the make command gives an error:
mps_roots.cc: In function ‘octave_value_list Fmps_roots(const octave_value_list&, int)’:
mps_roots.cc:96:19: error: ‘const class octave_value’ has no member named ‘is_map’
   96 |       if (args(1).is_map())
      |                   ^~~~~~
mps_roots.cc:182:29: error: ‘class Array<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >’ has no member named ‘length’
  182 |         if (starting_points.length() != n -1)
      |                             ^~~~~~

How can I compile MPSolve on my system?

The website you link mentions "Additional modules (such as Octave and Python bindings) can be installed with the packages octave-mpsolve and python-mpsolve." Did you try installing octave-mpsolve?

I did try "sudo apt-get install octave-mpsolve python-mpsolve" which tells me that these packages cannot be located. Furthermore, I can't find anything online about any packages called "octave-mpsolve" or "python-mpsolve" which can potentially be installed. My understanding (perhaps wrong) is that these "additional modules" which the webpage mentions are bundled with the downloadable binaries, rather than being needed for compilation in the first place.

Please compare your Octave version number with that required for this tool. You likely have an older Octave.
